# Type size_t could not be resolve C++ eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, size-t

I'll develop one application in c++ using eclipse. My problem is used of size_t type variable work fine in first.cpp file but not work in second.cpp file for the same project.

Declaration of variable like

```
size_t myVariable;
```

It says "Type size_t could not be resolve"

Comment: have u  included header file in second.cpp for size_t?

Comment: Change it to `std::size_t` and do an `#include <cstddef>` at the top.

Comment: @Nipun Ya I add all header file but in my first.cpp file used procedure oriented code and my second.cpp file contains object oriented code.

Comment: @Simple Sorry actully i used std::size_t thenn also it's not work...!

Comment: @Devani, better you post your code. Without that it would be difficult to understand. If u have VS editor, try to run same on that as well. This will help u to identify whether it is coming because eclipse editor or not as u mentioned in your question.

Comment: @Nipun sorry but i am not able to post code because of restriction but i am sure that in both file all header files are incuded

Comment: @Devani, may be this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413080/eclipse-3-7-cannot-resolve-types-in-c-editor

Comment: @Nipun Thanks if you found some solution then please notify me..

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an include in your second.cpp file.
Try to add i.e.:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

in this file. Then `size_t` should be resolvable.
The header files within `size_t` is defined are the following:

```
<cstddef> <cstdio> <cstdlib> <cstring> <ctime> <cwchar>
```

See also: [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/size_t/)

In case you don't use `using namespace std;` you have to write `std::size_t` though. If you want `size_t` in your global namespace, you can include  instead - but I would advise against it, because it's deprecated and pollutes the global namespace.

Comment: MSDN says STDDEF.H for size_t

Comment: `stddef.h` is deprecated in C++, because it places each name in an global namespace. It's better to use `<cstddef>` instead. See also [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header).

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef unsigned int size_t;
```

helps. correct me if wrong.

Comment: i cannot find site_t in visualstudio2017-workload-nativedesktop