# Eclipse kepler doesn't recognize uint16_t

Tags: c++, eclipse

I using eclipse kepler for C/C++ developers on windows 7 for ARM programming. For toolchain I using CodeSourcary_Lite_for_ARM_EABI.

I have problem with eclipse preprocessor, because they doesn't recognized uint16_t type, but they recognized all other types defined in stint.h. Despite the error, code is builded normaly.

Pleas help me, because all errors make my code unreadeble.

**Update:**

I was resolved the problem :)
I uninstaled toolchain and instaled newer version of CodeSourcary_Lite_for_ARM_EABI.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413080/eclipse-3-7-cannot-resolve-types-in-c-editor) is the reason? Another more sensible option in the long term, is to nuke Eclipse from your hard drive and replace it with a working IDE.

Comment: A sensible solution is to appreciate that Eclipse CDT is a very powerful IDE and works amazingly well. There are no other IDEs that compare. CDT does amazing semantic and syntactic as you type work. What I can recommend is stay current, Kepler is 3 major eclipse releases ago and even more than that for CDT (CDT releases more often than Kepler). Have a look at http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_pref_build_scanner_discovery.htm which tells you how to identify when/if your scanner discovery has gone wrong and how to diagnose it.